# Confidence and Prediction Bounds in matlab for custom equation

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, curve-fitting

I have the experimental date as:

```
x=[10; 23; 28; 60; 200; 233; 305]

y=[140e6; 120e6; 116e6; 100e6; 70e6; 65e6; 60e6]
```

I used my own equation to plot a curve fitting.

Assume my equation is defined as: G = a + b + c

How can I plot the confidence boundary (i.e. upper and lower boundary)?

Actually, I saw this link

http://uk.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/confidence-and-prediction-bounds.html

but I need your help to apply it to my situation please.

Comment: What is your code for the fitting?

Comment: using the curve fitting tools in matlab. Just need to put the curve equation in the custom equation.

Comment: You can use tools -> prediction bounds, but I don't get how your equation relates to your data, where do x and y come in?

Comment: Thanks! your comment is helpful and appreciated. :)